# French date format

Tags: php

I am a newbie in PHP & wordpress. I wanted to know how to make this codde renders the date formating in french (e.g. 5 Fev) when your on the french side but in english format in English (e.g. Jan 5)

Here is my code:

```
<?php
if (strtolower(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE) == 'en') {$sidePosts = get_posts('cat=3,4,5,19&posts_per_page=5&order=DESC&orderby=date');}
if (strtolower(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE) == 'fr') {$sidePosts = get_posts('cat=9,10,11,17&posts_per_page=5&order=DESC&orderby=date');}
foreach($sidePosts as $sidePosts) {
    $array = (array) $sidePosts;
    print("<li>");
    print("<span class='date'>".get_the_time('M j', $array[ID])."</span>");
    print("<a href='".get_permalink($array[ID])."' title='".$array[post_title]."'>".$array[post_title]."</a>");
    print("</li>");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace this:

```
print("<span class='date'>".get_the_time('M j', $array[ID])."</span>");
```

with this:

```
if (strtolower(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE) == 'en') 
{
    print("<span class='date'>".get_the_time('M j', $array[ID])."</span>");

}
else {
    print("<span class='date'>".get_the_time('j M', $array[ID])."</span>");
}
```

In the long run you may want to look at using a plugin to do this since  you will likely have to redo this change after updating wordpress.

You may also want to read this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time and 
http://gettingeek.com/internationalize-localize-a-wordpress-theme-guide-for-dummies-part-1-introduction-70.html